# Use Methods and Functions to Prompt User for Inputting Data and Outputting Results of Calculations

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, function, methods, vb6

I am stuck on  a specific part of this VISUAL BASIC question. Here it is.

```
Write a program that is used to perform calculations on two numbers. 
• The program should make use of the following methods: 
1. Main() – Calls method getdata() 
2. Getdata() – asks the user for data and type of calculation to perform then calls 
the respective calculation method i.e. 
– Add() 
– Subtract() 
– Multiply() 
– Divide() 
3. Displaydata() – called by the main method to display the results obtained
```

This is what I have done so far............................................................

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a, b, c As Integer

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter first number: ")
        a = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter second number: ")
        b = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Which type of calculation would you like to perform? ")
        Console.WriteLine("1. Addition ")
        Console.WriteLine("2. Multiplication ")
        Console.WriteLine("3. Addition ")
        Console.WriteLine("4. Subtraction ")

        c = Console.ReadLine()

        If c = 1 Then
            add(a, b)
        Else
            If c = 2 Then
                subtract(a, b)
            Else
                If c = 3 Then
                    multiply(a, b)
                Else
                    divide(a, b)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub add(ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of the two numbers is " & y + z)
    End Sub

    Sub subtract(ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("The difference between the two numbers is " & y - z)
    End Sub

    Sub multiply(ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("The product of the two numbers is " & y * z)
    End Sub

    Sub divide(ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("The division of the two numbers is " & y / z)
    End Sub

End Module
```

As you can see, my main problem is to introduce the getData() and the displayData() functions to prompt for user input and display results. I have tried so many times but every time I get at least 25 errors and the program would not run. I would really appreciate any sort of assistance. Thank you in advance.

And as asked, here is my failed attempt to insert the getData() and displayData() methods.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As Integer

        input = Function getData()
        Function displayData()
        Console.WriteLine(c)
    End Function

    Function getData()
        Dim a, b, c As Integer

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter first number: ")
        a = Console.ReadLine()
        Return (a)

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter second number: ")
        b = Console.ReadLine()
        Return (b)

        Console.WriteLine("Which type of calculation would you like to perform? ")
        Console.WriteLine("1. Addition ")
        Console.WriteLine("2. Multiplication ")
        Console.WriteLine("3. Addition ")
        Console.WriteLine("4. Subtraction ")

        c = Console.ReadLine()

        If c = 1 Then
            add(a, b)
        Else
            If c = 2 Then
                subtract(a, b)
            Else
                If c = 3 Then
                    multiply(a, b)
                Else
                    divide(a, b)
                End If
            End If
        End If

        Return (c)
    End Function

    Sub add(ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of the two numbers is " & y + z)
    End Sub

    Sub subtract(ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("The difference between the two numbers is " & y - z)
    End Sub

    Sub multiply(ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("The product of the two numbers is " & y * z)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Why don't you show your failed attempts to insert the getdata and displaydata?. In this way we could help you to understand and fix them

Comment: You'll need to obtain clearance from your teacher to copy your homework assignment on a site like this.  Any content here may be freely copied by anybody, under the terms of the cc-by-sa 3.0 license.  Pretty doubtful your teacher agrees with his work being redistributed under that license, especially since you didn't follow the license rules.  A link to the original content and a link to identify the author are minimal requirements.

Comment: Man, that is one messed up code...What have you done there o.O

Comment: @Steve, I have included my failed attempt at inserting the said methods

Comment: @Hans Passant, thank you for your critic...but I am not a student as you openly declare,therefore I am not able to obtain a clearance. I am learning VB separately for use in my personal projects.

Comment: There are numerous errors as you have already discovered. Check the syntax to use when you call a function (it is different when you declare a function) then you need to understand the concept of passing variable to function and returning values. (While at it try to understand what is a global variable)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have some notes you should take into consideration while you are writing vb.net.

**Don't declare your varibles in one line.**

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
```

**Give meaningful names to your varibles.**

```
Dim FirstNumber As Integer
Dim SecondNumber As Integer
Dim Operation As Integer
```

**Use Select Case instead of multiple ElseIf**

```
Select Case Operation
        Case 1
            add(FirstNumber, SecondNumber)
        Case 2
            multiply(FirstNumber, SecondNumber)
        Case 3
            subtract(FirstNumber, SecondNumber)
        Case 4
            divide(FirstNumber, SecondNumber)
End Select
```

**Use Function instead of Sub to return a value.**
Instead of using all those Subs, you can use a function that will return the result, something like:

```
Function add(ByVal y As Integer, ByVal z As Integer) As Integer
    Return y + z
End Function
```

As to your question. The problem is that after you execute the sub, the program will be shut down, because it has been finished. In order to prevent that and to enable to see the result, write at the end of the main sub `Console.ReadLine()`, which will prevent the program to shut down.

Also, you have a mistake in the operation selection - you wrote addition two time...

Comment: thank you for the very valuable information. Indeed like you said, the program shut down as soon as i input the first number and I was wondering why. I will incorporate your recommendation ASAP.

Comment: Seems like most of y'all buried your heads in the sand even after much outspoken critic.

Comment: hmm...If there is a particular question you have, just edit your question and we will try our best.